# Ответ вк бота (через request) на сообщение, python

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    keyboard = create_keyboard_school()
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
        request = event.text.lower()
        if request.lower()=='1':
            send_msg(event.user_id, "&#128527;")
        elif request.lower()=='2':
            while (True):
                if request.lower() != '2':
                    qw=request.lower()
                    send_msg(event.user_id,qw)
                    break
                else:
                    continue
        else:
            send_msg(event.user_id,"qw")
```

Данный код не работает из-за странной ошибки в отступах(хз в чём проблема). Я пытался реализовать конструкцию if request.lower== и т.д., но что бы только после введения,к примеру, 2, можно было получить свой же текст. Пожалуйста, скажите как это по умному реализовать, чтобы он хотя бы в бесконечный цикл не влетал. Если ещё объясните где я напутал с отступами -большое спасибо.

Comment: Зачем **дважды** приводить текст к нижнему регистру? Питон с первого раза отлично понимает, что надо сделать. И приводить к нижнему регистру ради сравнения с цифрой тоже странная затея.

Comment: Это из-за того что это тестовый бот... Никак на работу не влияет

Comment: Но да, за замечание спасибо, я на эту часть кода вообще не смотрел ( работает, не тормозит). Исправлю, мб чуть получше реагировать будет.

Answer (score 0):

Так, проблема с отступами решилось простым стиранием и расставлением заново, сейчас он ловит бесконечный цикл.
Код с нормальными отсутпами:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
keyboard = create_keyboard_school()
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
    request = event.text.lower()
    if request.lower()=='1':
        send_msg(event.user_id, "&#128527;")
    elif request.lower()=='2':
        while (True):
            if request.lower() != '2' :      
                qw=request.lower()
                send_msg(event.user_id,qw)
                break
            else:
                continue
    else:
        send_msg(event.user_id,"qw")
```